# Set theory - What is $n(\emptyset) =?$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Context from my School Textbook.

> A set containing no elements is called the empty set or null set or void set. 
>   Reading Notation : 
>   The empty set or null set or void set is denoted by the symbol $\emptyset$ or $\{ \}$.

The concept of empty set plays a key role in the study of sets just like the role of the number zero in the study of number system.
Think and answer! What is $n(\emptyset)$?

Comment: What does $n\{\}$ denote? Cardinality?

Comment: That's where I'm confused.

Comment: If you were to go just a page or two before, I'm sure they would have **very explicitly** stated what $n(\cdot)$ represents.  If you had taken the time to read that, you wouldn't have needed to ask this question.  Downvoting for lack of research effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without additional information, I can only guess. But I think it's likely that $n(A)$, for a given set $A$, is the number of elements of $A$. Since the empty set $\emptyset$ has no elements, we thus have $n(\emptyset) = 0$.

Comment: If set A has no elements then it can be written A = { } or A = Φ. Can Φ be treated as set like A written as Φ = { }

Comment: @HarishRaja of course.  Why wouldn't it?

Comment: So, I understand like, if any set ,For example, set X and Y have no elements. Then the set X = Y = Φ = { } where Φ is the other name of set X and Y.

Comment: Yes, two sets $X,Y$ are equal if and only if they have the same element. Hence there is a unique empty set - the set with no elements.

Comment: Is it usual to n({ }) = Φ ?

Comment: or is it usual to write n(Φ) = { }

Comment: Unless you interpret the empty set as a number (which I doubt), neither is appropriate. $n(A)$ is the *number of elements* of $A$.

Comment: You still haven't given a definition of $n(\,)$.

Comment: Even, I don't know the definition of $n(\,)$ and not mentioned in the Book .So, then it must be a mistake from my Textbook designers.

Comment: Is Φ a value like (null = Φ) or a set named Φ which has no elements.

Comment: $\emptyset$ is (/represents) the unique set which has no elements.

Comment: the thing is I got confused with letter Φ as a set or a value . That's it , I got it.

Comment: You're welcome :-)